# Igualar variables de adentro por las de afuera en un SP - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una duda la cual quiero entender lógicamente como funciona

Por ejemplo tengo el siguiente Script sencillo como ejemplo

```
DECLARE @FechaIni = '2022-01-01'
DECLARE @FechaFin = '2022-01-31'

SELECT
 c.Nombre
,d.Identificacion
FROM Datos d
INNER JOIN Clientes c ON c.Id = d.Id
WHERE d.FechaCreacion BETWEEN @FechaIni AND @FechaFin
```

El cual a nivel de consulta funciona perfecto, sin embargo cuando lo creo como un Procedimiento Almacenado

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InformacionCliente @FechaIni DATE,@FechaFin DATE 

AS
BEGIN

--DECLARE @FechaIni = '2022-01-01'
--DECLARE @FechaFin = '2022-01-31'

SELECT
 c.Nombre
,d.Identificacion
FROM Datos d
INNER JOIN Clientes c ON c.Id = d.Id
WHERE d.FechaCreacion BETWEEN @FechaIni AND @FechaFin

END
```

Y lo ejecuto **EXEC dbo.InformacionCliente '2022-01-01','2022-01-31'**

Este NUNCA ejecuta o se tarda demasiado tiempo en hacerlo

Sin embargo, si hago la siguiente modificación al SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InformacionCliente @FechaIni1 DATE,@FechaFin1 DATE 

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @FechaIni = @FechaIni1
DECLARE @FechaFin = @FechaFin1

SELECT
 c.Nombre
,d.Identificacion
FROM Datos d
INNER JOIN Clientes c ON c.Id = d.Id
WHERE d.FechaCreacion BETWEEN @FechaIni AND @FechaFin

END
```

El SP se ejecuta perfectamente y rápido, mi consulta es, ¿Cómo funciona esto lógicamente? o si alguien me puede explicar si esto es recomendable y cuando realizarlo

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te ocurre, se llama **parameter sniffing**, y aunque hay varias técnicas para solucionarlo, no existe un camino perfecto.

La que has escogido en mi opinión no es la mejor, pero funciona.
Prueba esto.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InformacionCliente @FechaIni1 DATE,@FechaFin1 DATE 

AS
BEGIN


SELECT
 c.Nombre
,d.Identificacion
FROM Datos d
INNER JOIN Clientes c ON c.Id = d.Id
WHERE d.FechaCreacion BETWEEN @FechaIni1 AND @FechaFin1
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN);

END
```

Usando el hint `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)`, ya le indicas al motor que el plan de ejecución debe de estar preparado para esta causística.

En este hilo de stackOverflow en inglés te explican el how to.

[Optimize for unknown vs option recompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432794/what-are-the-main-differences-between-optionoptimize-for-unknown-and-optionre)

Tienes más técnicas en este otro artículo de Dave Pinal

[Parameter Sniffing Optimize for Unknown](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2019/12/21/sql-server-parameter-sniffing-and-optimize-for-unknown/)